# Spans as inline-blocks floating dependent on seemingly unrelated code

Tags: php, css, tags

I created a div to contain tags, the tags are spans with "display: inline-block, float: left". The tags work everywhere in my project except when I use php to write a div "tag_block" and put the tag spans inside, the weird thing is that for the first element that gets rendered, the spans are centered, then as I scroll down through other elements, the positioning slowly shifts over to the right, stopping at the right, and occasionally jumping around a bit.

Does this sound like a browser issue? I'm quite stumped!

The "float: left" seems to be superceded by something arbitrary that changes for each element the tag block gets printed in.

```
<div class="tag_block">
    <span class="tag">Tag0</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag1</span>
</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle with comments in code (http://jsfiddle.net/livvyjeffs/4uAp4/5/)

So I really minimized the problem, and for some reason, the text inside the block on top affects where the spans begin to display in the block below it. Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't combine inline-block and float, this will likely lead to unexpected behavior throughout different browsers. Floats are for blocks. Not for inline-blocks. I suppose that it will work just fine, when you remove the float. If not you have to explain a little bit better, what you would like to achieve and it would be nice to have a fiddle or a plunker.

Comment: I am not sure, but be careful with whitespace, it likes to screw your layout.

Comment: Can you provide a replicable example of your code in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `display: inline-block` you shouldn't have to float. Float is meant for block level elements. This may be the cause of your issue. `display: inline-block` is technically doing the same thing as `float: left` anyway since it is putting the elements inline next to each other.

Another issue might be that your floats are stacking inside of the `tag_block` div. If you float all of the elements inside of a div it will not clear itself. If that is the case, you could have the next set of elements butting up against the former. You can solve this by using a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html#.UoEiGpQ6V8s). Add that code to your CSS and add the clearfix class to the parent element `tag_block`. Again, you should be able to avoid this by simply removing the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Whew... the problem is that one of the divs in the container above the one having problems expanded past the boundaries of the box, causing the alignment of the div below it (the problem div) to be dependent upon the one above it.

Here is the [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/livvyjeffs/4uAp4/6/) highlited.

And the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/livvyjeffs/4uAp4/7/), set the problem div to height: 0 (or something that doesn't overlap the boundary).

```
.poster{
     height: 0;
}
```

**Stack Etiquette?** I tried to delete my post instead of answering my own problem. Seems like my problem is stuck here for now. Thanks for all the help!